# Old Skool CSS Websafe Font Callout

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm working on a customers website and they insist I use EXACTLY the same font they had before.  The previous (drupal) site had a Cascading Style Sheet callout:

```
 body { font: 76%/170% Arial,sans-serif; }
```

As I understand it, that correlates to a Websafe font, where the browser looks to the users operating system and tries to match a font, in this case with Arial first and if not,  Sans-serif.  Nothing is downloaded from the web.

Based on my testing, the native font size seems to be 16px, and the native line height seems to be 20px. The fractional percentage numbers indicate font-size (as a ratio from 16px) and line-height (as a ratio from the calculated font-size).  In this case font-size observed (via WhatFont) = 12.1667px and line-height of 20.6833px

The combination shown above seems to have been a very common Drupal selection, at least it would appear so from my Google searches on this topic.

This whole thing seems way odd.  I would think...

```
 body{ font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px line-height:21px}
```

makes more sense, communicates the intent clearly for those who follow, etc.  Why would anybody do the `% / %` system for identifying font-size?  Is that native height ALWAYS 16px? This feels like obfuscation for nothing.  Is there a significant advantage anywhere?  Why would anybody code like this?  What am I missing here?

Comment: `Is that native height ALWAYS 16px?` No, that's just a general guide. The end user can set the base font size to anything, so it's always important to make sure your layout works at various font sizes.

Comment: Can I extrapolate from your note that the purpose of coding a site like this is to allow the user some sense of control of font size within their browser?  I know that when you zoom in and zoom out, the apparent font size doesn't change, but perhaps native font size is a more 'permanent' accessibility style setting? I'm still trying to understand, why would anyone do a website this way?

Comment: I've met people who set the base font size of their computer to something quite large, to make things easier to read. A lot of sites they would visit looked awful, because of things like fixed-height containers, meaning that the large text was spilling out and overlapping other elements etc. So it's important to make a layout flexible enough to accommodate different font sizes. Now that most browsers zoom the whole page rather than just text, it's not as big an issue as it used to be, but it's still an issue.